# Javascript Scrollbar - Scrolls down but not up with clientY

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I am writing a scroll bar to replace scroll bar on the browser. I prefer to do it myself for the learning experience rather than use jQuery.

I got this code to work but I have a couple of issues:

1. It will scroll down, but won't scroll up.
2. When I click on the scroll bar element which is 100px long and 10px wide, the mouse pointer seems to snap to the top of the scroll bar element which looks unnatural for a scroll bar.

html:

```
<div id="portfolioScrollbar">
        <div id="scrollbarTrack"><a id="scrolla" href="#scrollbar"></a></div>
    <div id="pbody">
                      ...all the text stuff...
             </div>
     </div>
```

EDIT- NEW CODE 1/27/2013:

Javscript:

```
    function CloseContact() {
        setTimeout (addClose, 2200 );
        setTimeout (addContact, 2400 );
        var foo = document.getElementById("scrolla");
        foo.addEventListener( "mousedown", scrollObject.sbar1, false);
        foo.addEventListener( "mouseup", removeAll, false);
        foo.addEventListener( "mouseout", removeAll, false);
    }

    function removeAll(event) {
        console.log("REMOVEaLL");
        var foo = document.getElementById("scrolla");
        foo.removeEventListener("mouseup", scrollObject.sbar2, false); 
        foo.removeEventListener("mouseout", scrollObject.sbar2, false); 
        foo.removeEventListener("mousemove", scrollObject.sbar2, false); 
    }



var scrollObject = function (event) {

    var current = 0;
    var move = null;

    function sbar1(event) {
        console.log("mousedown");
        event.preventDefault();
        var foo = document.getElementById("scrolla");
        current = event.clientY;
        foo.addEventListener( "mousemove", sbar2, false);
    }

    function sbar2(event) {
//      console.log(event.clientY);
        event.preventDefault();
        var pbody = document.getElementById("pbody");
        var scroll = document.getElementById("scrolla");
        move = event.clientY - current;

        if (move != 78644 ) {
            console.log(move);
        scroll.style.marginTop =  move + "px";
        //current = move;
        }
    }

    return {
        sbar1: sbar1,
            sbar2: sbar2,
    }
}();
```

Comment: Can you share your mousemove handler?

Comment: Very sorry about that...I updated the posting with sbar2()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K. So your problem is, you're adjusting the margin to match the height of the click, which sets the edge of your scroller to the location of the mouse. This immediately triggers the mouseout handler, which removes the scroll handler.

I added some logging to your code, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = document.getElementById("scrolla");
    var pbody = document.getElementById("pbody");
    var scroll = document.getElementById("scrolla");


function contact() {    
    foo.addEventListener( "mousedown", sbar1, false);
    foo.addEventListener( "mouseup", function() { console.log("### removing mousemove"); foo.removeEventListener("mousemove", sbar2, false) }, false);
    foo.addEventListener( "mouseout", function() { console.log("### removing mouseout"); foo.removeEventListener("mousemove", sbar2, false) }, false);
}

function sbar1() {
console.log("@@@ adding listener");
    foo.addEventListener( "mousemove", sbar2, false);
}


function sbar2(event) {
console.log("moving");
    var h = event.clientY;
console.log(h);
    scroll.style.marginTop = h + "px";
}


scroll.addEventListener('click', contact, false);

contact();
</script>
```

And ended up with the following output on click:

```
@@@ adding listener 
moving 
67 
### removing mouseout 
### removing mousemove
```

I'll let you explore your current approach, but you're probably going to want to calculate the difference in the mouse position over the drag rather than moving the scroller directly to the position of the mouse.

For example, when they click initially, you store the value of clientY. Then as they move the mouse up or down, you compare the new clientY against the initial clientY, and apply the difference to the scroller's margin-top.

Sound good?

Comment: thanks, this sets me in the right direction. now i need to figure out how to register a mouseup event when the mouse is outside the element...without adding another event listener on outside of that element(seems like there is a better solution).

Comment: Well, you can probably have the mouseup handler on the scrollbar. Aren't you using it like a gripper? You could conceivably track the click origin at all times, but set it to -100 or something when you mouse up. Then, if in the mousemove handler, if you had the negative value as the origin, you just ignored the event, and don't adjust the margin.

Comment: I updated with some refinement(please see original post edited), but I am still having issues with scrolling up. The first time I scroll the gripper, I can scroll up and down. But after I scroll the gripper, when I click on it a second time **and I slightly scroll up** for some reason it equates to 1 immediately and snaps the element/gripper up to the top.